# Are PDF zero-days still being widely used?

Tags: zero-day, pdf

Even after all those patches for PDF programs, would you estimate that there are still many zero-days out there? If so, would you estimate that these zero-days are being widely used for various malicious purposes?

Just trying to get a better sense for how risky PDF is for both the average consumer and software engineers whose personal electronics could be the entry point for hackers.

Comment: just as many as ever for un-updated equipment, which is all some of the fresh attacks even work on. that said, both major browsers now use a much safer PDF display tech than the "smart and powerful" adobe reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are definitely still out there. I come across them at least on a weekly basis around the place. I'm not sure about your second statement, but I will say that they are just as popular of an entry point as they have ever been.